# Python inaccurate curve fit

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scipy, curve-fitting

```
Temp    k(T)
298   6.66E-63
300   1.48E-62
350   3.58E-55
400   1.25E-49
450   2.57E-45
500   7.30E-42
550   4.90E-39
600   1.12E-36
650   1.11E-34
700   5.72E-33
750   1.75E-31
800   3.49E-30
850   4.92E-29
900   5.17E-28
950   4.24E-25
1000  2.83E-26
```

Above is the given kinetic data, I am trying to fit this data and plot the same.

## Curvefitting

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import pandas as pd
plt.style.use('ggplot')

#Generate data
df=pd.read_excel('py_curvefit.xlsx')
T=df.Temp  #xdata
def reacKine(T,A,n,Ea):
    return A*((T/298)**n)*np.exp(-Ea/(0.008314*T))
kt=df['k(T)']  #ydata
#rectifying an erroneous value      
kt[14]=4.24*10**(-27)  
popt,pcov=curve_fit(reacKine,T,kt)
A,n,Ea=popt
plt.plot(T,np.log(kt),'g-',label='given data')
plt.plot(T,np.log(reacKine(T,*popt)),'ro',label='fit')
plt.xlabel('Temperature [K]')
plt.ylabel('log of reaction coefficient')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

It says optimal parameters not found for the function. How do I rectify this. I am hoping to see a good fit. Is it because of the exponential term?

Comment: It'd be helpful if you shared your results, and provided a better sense of what  your expectations are and how they differ from the results.

Comment: I edited it and now I am using a more accurate function for the kinetic data,  it says optimal parameters not found.

Comment: On this line what are you trying to do? `popt,pcov=curve_fit(reacKine,T,kt)`. Your function `reacKine` doesn't have any arguments...

Comment: curve fit requires function, xdata and the y data. My function does have arguments A,n and Ea

Comment: even after rectifying that, it says optimal parameters not found

Comment: That's a candidate for fitting the logarithmic data, is it not? Shifts the weights, though.

Answer (score 3):

This is a sensitive problem (as is typical when exponentials are involved).  For a problem like this, it is important to have a pretty good initial guess for the parameters.

If you experiment with the parameters, you'll find that `A` has to be very small.  The default initial guess that is used by `curve_fit` for all the parameters is 1, and 1 is far too big for `A`.  If I use 1e-10 for the initial guess for `A`

```
popt, pcov = curve_fit(reacKine, T, kt, p0=(1e-10, 1, 1))
```

I get the following error from `curve_fit`:

```
RuntimeError: Optimal parameters not found: Number of calls to function has reached maxfev = 800.
```

So let's increase `maxfev` to, say, `2000`:

```
popt, pcov = curve_fit(reacKine, T, kt, p0=(1e-10, 1, 1), maxfev=2000)
```

I got the same error.  When I increased it to `100000`, the function succeeded.

Here's a script that includes the updated call to `curve_fit`, followed by the plot generated by the script.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


T = np.array([298, 300, 350, 400, 450, 500, 550, 600, 650, 700, 750, 800,
              850, 900, 950, 1000])
kt = np.array([6.66e-63, 1.48e-62, 3.58e-55, 1.25e-49, 2.57e-45, 7.30e-42,
               4.90e-39, 1.12e-36, 1.11e-34, 5.72e-33, 1.75e-31, 3.49e-30,
               4.92e-29, 5.17e-28, 4.24e-27, 2.83e-26])

def reacKine(T,A,n,Ea):
    return A*((T/298)**n)*np.exp(-Ea/(0.008314*T))

popt, pcov = curve_fit(reacKine, T, kt, p0=(1e-10, 1, 1), maxfev=100000)


plt.plot(T, kt, '.', label='data')
tt = np.linspace(T[0], T[-1], 160)
kk = reacKine(tt, *popt)
semilogy = True
if semilogy:
    plt.semilogy(tt, kk, 'k-', alpha=0.3, label='fit')
    results_xy = (700, 1e-45)
else:
    plt.plot(tt, kk, 'k-', alpha=0.3, label='fit')
    results_xy = (300, 1.5e-26)

plt.annotate(xy=results_xy,
            s=('Fit Results:\n  $A\,$  = %.4g\n  $n\,$  = %.4g\n  $E_{a}$ = %.4g' %
               tuple(popt)))
plt.xlabel('T')
plt.ylabel('k(T)')
plt.legend(framealpha=1, shadow=True)
plt.show()
```

[image: plot]

---

P.S. @MNewville might be able to suggest a better way to do this fit using [lmfit](http://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/).

Comment: Sure. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Note, you can get estimates for `p0` by fitting the log data first without any `p0`. So no *educated guess* required and automation possible. Anyhow, you are right: even then the `maxfev` needs to be incresed. (10000 works for me)

Comment: Please note that I did not provide any p0 initial parameter estimates in my example, in pyeq3 this is unnecessary as the genetic algorithm Differential Evolution is used to automatically determine them, similarly to what the scipy.optimize.differential_evolution module can be used for. You can provide p0 estimates when using pyeq3, though they are not required as you see in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I get the following parameters and fit statistics using the below code with the pyeq3 fitting library:

```
Fitting target of sum of squared absolute error = 7.93711173898e-62
Fitted Parameters:
    A = 3.6814349968228987E-12
    Ea = 2.8663497636217801E+02
    n = 1.6329619761384757E+00

Degress of freedom error 13
Degress of freedom regression 2
Root Mean Squared Error (RMSE): 7.04322002841e-32
R-squared: 0.9999999999
R-squared adjusted: 0.999999999884
Model F-statistic: 64790385432.5
Model F-statistic p-value: 1.11022302463e-16
Model log-likelihood: 1124.98750379
Model AIC: -140.248437973
Model BIC: -140.103577588

Individual Parameter Statistics:
Coefficient A = 3.6814349968228987E-12
    std error: 1.67464E-25
    t-stat: 8.99615E+00
    p-stat: 6.05074E-07
    95 percent confidence intervals: [2.79736E-12, 4.56551E-12]
Coefficient Ea = 2.8663497636217801E+02
    std error: 1.69556E-01
    t-stat: 6.96102E+02
    p-stat: 0.00000E+00
    95 percent confidence intervals: [2.85745E+02, 2.87525E+02]
Coefficient n = 1.6329619761384757E+00
    std error: 2.59159E-03
    t-stat: 3.20770E+01
    p-stat: 9.19265E-14
    95 percent confidence intervals: [1.52298E+00, 1.74294E+00]

Coefficient Covariance Matrix:
    [ 2.74285036e+37   2.75990923e+49  -3.41210380e+48]
    [ 2.75990923e+49   2.77711499e+61  -3.43328442e+60]
    [-3.41210380e+48  -3.43328442e+60   4.24469499e+59]

import os, sys, inspect
import pyeq3

functionString = 'A*((X/298)**n)*exp(-Ea/(0.008314*X))'

data = '''
298   6.66e-63
300   1.48e-62
350   3.58e-55
400   1.25e-49
450   2.57e-45
500   7.30e-42
550   4.90e-39
600   1.12e-36
650   1.11e-34
700   5.72e-33
750   1.75e-31
800   3.49e-30
850   4.92e-29
900   5.17e-28
950   4.24e-27
1000  2.83e-26
'''

# note that the constructor is passed the function string here
equation = pyeq3.Models_2D.UserDefinedFunction.UserDefinedFunction(inUserFunctionString = functionString)

pyeq3.dataConvertorService().ConvertAndSortColumnarASCII(data, equation, False)

equation.Solve()

##########################################################

print("Equation:", equation.GetDisplayName(), str(equation.GetDimensionality()) + "D")
print("Fitting target of", equation.fittingTargetDictionary[equation.fittingTarget], '=', equation.CalculateAllDataFittingTarget(equation.solvedCoefficients))
print("Fitted Parameters:")
for i in range(len(equation.solvedCoefficients)):
    print("    %s = %-.16E" % (equation.GetCoefficientDesignators()[i], equation.solvedCoefficients[i]))


equation.CalculateModelErrors(equation.solvedCoefficients, equation.dataCache.allDataCacheDictionary)
print()

##########################################################

equation.CalculateCoefficientAndFitStatistics()

if equation.upperCoefficientBounds or equation.lowerCoefficientBounds:
    print('You entered coefficient bounds. Parameter statistics may')
    print('not be valid for parameter values at or near the bounds.')
    print()

print('Degress of freedom error',  equation.df_e)
print('Degress of freedom regression',  equation.df_r)

if equation.rmse == None:
    print('Root Mean Squared Error (RMSE): n/a')
else:
    print('Root Mean Squared Error (RMSE):',  equation.rmse)

if equation.r2 == None:
    print('R-squared: n/a')
else:
    print('R-squared:',  equation.r2)

if equation.r2adj == None:
    print('R-squared adjusted: n/a')
else:
    print('R-squared adjusted:',  equation.r2adj)

if equation.Fstat == None:
    print('Model F-statistic: n/a')
else:
    print('Model F-statistic:',  equation.Fstat)

if equation.Fpv == None:
    print('Model F-statistic p-value: n/a')
else:
    print('Model F-statistic p-value:',  equation.Fpv)

if equation.ll == None:
    print('Model log-likelihood: n/a')
else:
    print('Model log-likelihood:',  equation.ll)

if equation.aic == None:
    print('Model AIC: n/a')
else:
    print('Model AIC:',  equation.aic)

if equation.bic == None:
    print('Model BIC: n/a')
else:
    print('Model BIC:',  equation.bic)


print()
print("Individual Parameter Statistics:")
for i in range(len(equation.solvedCoefficients)):
    if type(equation.tstat_beta) == type(None):
        tstat = 'n/a'
    else:
        tstat = '%-.5E' %  ( equation.tstat_beta[i])

    if type(equation.pstat_beta) == type(None):
        pstat = 'n/a'
    else:
        pstat = '%-.5E' %  ( equation.pstat_beta[i])

    if type(equation.sd_beta) != type(None):
        print("Coefficient %s = %-.16E, std error: %-.5E" % (equation.GetCoefficientDesignators()[i], equation.solvedCoefficients[i], equation.sd_beta[i]))
    else:
        print("Coefficient %s = %-.16E, std error: n/a" % (equation.GetCoefficientDesignators()[i], equation.solvedCoefficients[i]))
    print("          t-stat: %s, p-stat: %s, 95 percent confidence intervals: [%-.5E, %-.5E]" % (tstat,  pstat, equation.ci[i][0], equation.ci[i][1]))

print()
print("Coefficient Covariance Matrix:")
for i in  equation.cov_beta:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

The (obligatory?) lmfit answer:

You might find lmfit useful.  For the way this problem is framed, it doesn't add too much but gives a better abstraction for curve-fitting and fitting Parameters.  Similar to @WarrenWeskesser's answer, it would look like

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from lmfit import Model

T = np.array([298, 300, 350, 400, 450, 500, 550, 600, 650, 700, 750, 800,
          850, 900, 950, 1000])
kt = np.array([6.66e-63, 1.48e-62, 3.58e-55, 1.25e-49, 2.57e-45, 7.30e-42,
           4.90e-39, 1.12e-36, 1.11e-34, 5.72e-33, 1.75e-31, 3.49e-30,
           4.92e-29, 5.17e-28, 4.24e-27, 2.83e-26])

def reacKine(T, A, n, Ea):
    return A*((T/298)**n)*np.exp(-Ea/(0.008314*T))

react_model = Model(reacKine)
params = react_model.make_params(A=2.e-11, n=1, Ea=200)
result = react_model.fit(kt, params, T=T)

print(result.fit_report())

plt.plot(T, kt, 'bo', label='data')
plt.plot(T, result.best_fit, 'r--', label='fit')

plt.xlabel('T (K)')
plt.ylabel('k(T)')
plt.legend()
plt.gca().set_yscale('log')
plt.show()
```

When fitting with Python27 and scipy 1.0.0, this will show a fit similar to Warrens (I left out the annotations), and print a fit report of

```
[[Model]]
    Model(reacKine)
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # function evals   = 1294
    # data points      = 16
    # variables        = 3
    chi-square         = 0.000
    reduced chi-square = 0.000
    Akaike info crit   = -2219.907
    Bayesian info crit = -2217.590
[[Variables]]
    A:    1.3365e-10 +/- 5.06e-12 (3.79%) (init= 2e-11)
    n:   -0.02392420 +/- 0.034279 (143.28%) (init= 1)
    Ea:   299.843529 +/- 0.024996 (0.01%) (init= 200)
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are <  0.100)
    C(A, n)                      = -0.997 
    C(A, Ea)                     =  0.117
```

When fitting with Python36 and scipy 1.0.0 the report will be

```
[[Model]]
    Model(reacKine)
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # function evals   = 1618
    # data points      = 16
    # variables        = 3
    chi-square         = 0.000
    reduced chi-square = 0.000
    Akaike info crit   = -2289.381
    Bayesian info crit = -2287.063
[[Variables]]
    A:    3.6814e-12 +/- 4.09e-13 (11.12%) (init= 2e-11)
    n:    1.63296239 +/- 0.050923 (3.12%) (init= 1)
    Ea:   286.634973 +/- 0.411890 (0.14%) (init= 200)
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are <  0.100)
    C(A, n)                      = -1.000 
    C(A, Ea)                     =  1.000 
    C(n, Ea)                     = -1.000
```

These values are consistent with what Warren and James show.

I don't have a great explanation for why the results differ with Python version and especially why the correlations are > 0.999 for all variables in the Python36 version of the fit. But, with the parameters almost perfectly correlated and so many fit evaluations compared to data points, I would not be surprised if there were false minima and a complex correlation space.

Comment: *"I don't have a good explanation for the results are different or n<0, [...]"* When I run this code, it finds the same parameter values as in my answer and in James Phillips' answer.

Comment: When I run your example code on my machine and Py27 and scipy 0.19.1 or scipy 1.0.0, I get the same values for A, n, Ea I get with my lmfit example (A=1.337e-10, n=-0.0239, Ea=299.8).  When using Py36 and scipy 1.0.0, I get the same answers as you.  That's sort of weird...Again, A and n are highly and weirdly correlated.